# How to change variables in a cfg.py file from another file?

Tags: python, namespaces, save, config

I'm trying to create a config file to store some values that I'll be playing with in another file. But then I would like another main file to change the variables in the config file like so:

my config file:

```
#cfg.py
a = [2,3,4]
```

my main file:

```
#main.py
import cfg
print(cfg.a)
cfg.a[1] = 10
print(cfg.a)
```

It returns

```
[2,3,4]
[2,10,4]
```

which is fine, but when I close everything and look at my cfg.py again, the value of a in the cfg.py file did not change. Am I missing something? Am I supposed to use some sort of save function to make sure that I'm writing new values into the file? Or am I going about this in the totally wrong way?

It seems like I'm changing an instance of cfg.a instead of the reference to a in the original cfg.py file.

Comment: Use `configParser` instead

Comment: When you import a module, the fact that it's backed by a file is an implementation detail. Imagine the file doesn't really exist.

Comment: Yes that was good to know Peter, thanks. I shall be looking into other packages to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use "configobj" package with some minor adjustments.

The config file can be like this:

```
#cfg.py
a = 2,3,4
```

Then in python:

```
import configobj
conf = configobj.ConfigObj("cfg.py")
conf["a"][1] = 10
conf.write()  # Actually writes changes to file
```